# Installing certificate x509certifcate2 fails on Windows8

Tags: c#, certificate, windows-8.1

i'm trying to install some certificates to root store fore the currentuser.
On Windows 7 this is working perfectly but on Windows 8(specifically 8.1) this fails with a unknown error. I can install the certificate in other store's but not the root store.

Here's the code i'm using

```
filePaths = new List<X509Certificate2>();
        filePaths.Add(new X509Certificate2(eHealth_Ureg_Installer.Properties.Resources.belgiumrca));
        filePaths.Add(new X509Certificate2(eHealth_Ureg_Installer.Properties.Resources.belgiumrca2));
        filePaths.Add(new X509Certificate2(eHealth_Ureg_Installer.Properties.Resources.belgiumrca3));
        filePaths.Add(new X509Certificate2(eHealth_Ureg_Installer.Properties.Resources.belgiumrca4));
        filePaths.Add(new X509Certificate2(eHealth_Ureg_Installer.Properties.Resources.rootct2));
        try
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName., StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            foreach (var cert in filePaths)
            {
                store.Add(cert);
            }
            store.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You should try harder!